# Is equal() included by default in the global namespace?

Tags: c++

This is a question regarding the default global namespace in C++. I have the following code that compiles and runs properly using g++ clang-500.2.79.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using std::string;
using std::endl; 
using std::cout;

bool is_palindrome(const string& str){
    return equal(str.begin(), str.end(), str.rbegin());
}

int main(){

    cout << "Hello is a palindrome: " << is_palindrome("Hello") << endl;
    cout << "madam is a palindrome: " << is_palindrome("madam") << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My questions is, why does this code compile properly? I forgot to put `#include <algorithm>` and `using std::equal` at the beginning of my file. So the expected behaviour is for the compiler to complain.

The example at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal confirms that I should be using `std::equal`.

To investigate this further, I tried to track down *exactly* which version of the `equal()` function was being called. Being a relative newbie to C++ I don't know exactly how to do this either. I tried,

```
cout << "The function is: " << equal << endl;
```

Which generated a compiler error with some interesting information:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:771:5: 
note: 'std::equal' declared here
```

Try as I might, I can't find information about stl_algobase (or more probably, I most likely don't understand what I've found). Is `stl_algobase` a set of functions that are automatically included in the global namespace?

A further questions is: What is the proper way to track (code or otherwise) down which function is being called when you are dealing with potentially overloaded or template functions in C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`equal` is in the `std` namespace. What you are seeing is [*argument dependent lookup*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) (ADL). Because the arguments are in the `std`, the name lookup for `equal` considers that namespace too.

Here's a simplified example:

```
namespace foo
{
  struct Bar {};
}

namespace foo
{
  void bar(const Bar&) {}
  void bar(int) {}
}

int main()
{
  foo::Bar b;
  foo::bar(b);  // OK
  bar(b);       // ADL, OK
  foo::bar(42); // OK
  bar(42);      // No ADL: error: 'bar' was not declared in this scope
}
```

Comment: aha! But I guess for simple cases like this, ADL should not be relied upon. Is there a way to get the compiler to *warn* when ADL is being used?

Comment: @WilliamDenman I am not sure what you mean by "should not be relied on". It is an important part of the language, and without it many operator overloads would not work. The compiler has nothing to warn about. If you have an ambiguous overload because of ADL, you will get an error.

Comment: Perfect. So in your example, since the struct Bar is defined in the namespace foo, but int is not, the call to bar(b) can find the function void bar(const Bar&) but the call to bar(42) cannot find void bar(int)

Comment: cppreference [has a page on it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl), too.

Comment: @Cubbi Thanks. I replaced the old link with that one.

Comment: @juanchopanza: it should not be relied on generally because `std::string::const_iterator` is not guaranteed to be in namespace `std`. It might be `const char*`. So it would be somewhat useful to have a compiler warning that you're relying on behaviour specific to the implementation. But I think the questioner's specific code is OK because IIRC `rbegin()` is guaranteed to return (a specialization of) `std::reverse_iterator`. And of course in your example code it should be relied on :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes, that's kind of what I was thinking. It is quite interesting, to understand what is and what isn't guaranteed by the standard. C++ is a mystical beast ;).